# Lombok getter/setter references not showing correctly in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, lombok

I'm using Lombok 1.18.24 for a personal project added as a dependency with Apache Maven 3.8.6, using OpenJDK19 in VSCode 1.74.2, and everything works fine, but I've noticed that the Lombok annotations say `0 references` even though i use the generated getters and setters in many places.

This happens when I add the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations in some fields *(no matter the field type or access modifier)* instead of adding them to the whole class *(in some cases I don't need a getter and/or a setter for every class field)*.

Here are some screenshots with examples to see what i'm talking about:

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

[image: ss3]

No matter if I use the generated getter or setter for the field inside or outside its class, or if I use the field directly in its class, the `0 references` doesn't change for one or the other.

If I add the annotations to the whole class, those references don't show up, logically.

I tried to add the annotations in other parts, access/modify the fields via the generated getters/setters, access those fields directly inside their classes without using the generated methods, but it won't change.

Am I missing any VSCode configuration or extension for this to work correctly? Could it be a VSCode bug?

Thanks in advance!